# Frequency of elements in an array

Tags: java

I am relatively new to programming and i have been working on a java project for about 2 days that reads ten numbers and displays the frequency of occurrence of each number , while my code looks good and it run ,it doesnt seem to be able to count two numbers that are far apart even after sorting ,please i have run out of ideas and am open to suggestions

Here's my code:

```
public static void sortarray(int [] tennumbersarray ){
    for(int i =0 ;i<9;i++){
        int currentmin = tennumbersarray[i];
        int currentminindex = i;
        for(int j=i+1;j<10;j++){
            if(currentmin>tennumbersarray[j]){
                currentmin= tennumbersarray[j];
                currentminindex = j;
            }
        }
        if(currentminindex!=i){
            tennumbersarray[currentminindex]=tennumbersarray[i];
            tennumbersarray[i]=currentmin;
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int tennumbersarray [] = new int[10];
    for (int i =0 ;i<10;i++){
        String tennumbersstring = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a number :");
        tennumbersarray [i] = Integer.parseInt(tennumbersstring);
    }

    sortarray ( tennumbersarray);

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){            
         int count =1;
         for (int j=i+1;j<10;j++)
         {
             if(tennumbersarray[i]==tennumbersarray[j])
             {
                 count++;
             }
             else{
                 break;
             }
         }
         String output = ""+tennumbersarray[i] +"----> "+count;
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,output);
         i+=count;
     }
 }
 }
```

Comment: please format/indent the code and remove irrelevant method of the code, so we can see faster where possible causes are located at....

Comment: Also, use camelCase for variable names so it is easier to read: `tennumbersarray` => `tenNumbersArray`

Answer (score 1):

I think using [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) you can easily find the frequency of the number.

Ex:

```
int tenNumbersArray[] = new int[10];

tenNumbersArray[0] = 10;
tenNumbersArray[1] = 20;
tenNumbersArray[2] = 30;
tenNumbersArray[3] = 10;
tenNumbersArray[4] = 10;
tenNumbersArray[5] = 40;
tenNumbersArray[6] = 50;
tenNumbersArray[7] = 60;
tenNumbersArray[8] = 70;
tenNumbersArray[9] = 70;

HashMap<Integer, Integer> numberAndItsOcuurenceMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for (int num : tenNumbersArray) {
    Integer frequency = numberAndItsOcuurenceMap.get(num);
    numberAndItsOcuurenceMap.put(num, frequency != null ? frequency + 1 : 1);
}
```

OUTPUT:

> {50=1, 70=2, 20=1, 40=1, 10=3, 60=1, 30=1}

To get the frequency of the particular just pass the key to the map.
Ex:

```
 numberAndItsOcuurenceMap.get(10);
```

OUTPUT

> 3

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Map

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int tennumbersarray[] = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String tennumbersstring = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a number :");
        tennumbersarray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tennumbersstring);
    }
    Map<Integer, Integer> frequences = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for(int number : tennumbersarray)
        if(frequences.get(number) == null)
            frequences.put(number, 1);
        else
            frequences.put(number, frequences.get(number) + 1);

    for(Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : frequences.entrySet())
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, entry.getKey() + "----> " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resorting to sorting the array in order to count the frequency of its items is an idea that works, but it is not necessary. For instance, I'd use that approach if I were told that there was a file (on a Unix computer) with thousands of numbers and I was asked to count the number of times each number appears in that file **without writing any Java code**:

`cat file | sort -n | uniq -c`

But since you are tasked with writing one of your first Java programs, I introduce you to the idea of a hash table. Such a hash table, in Java, is realized using a `HashMap`, where keys are integers and values are also integers (for starters). Every time you encounter an integer, you increment its count:

```
public static Map<Integer, Long> count(int[] ints) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i : ints) {
        if (counter.containsKey(i)) 
            counter.put(i, counter.get(i) + 1);
        else
            counter.put(i, 1); // initialize
    }
    return counter; // here, we'll have each number mapped to 
                    // how many times it appears in ints {1: 23, 3: 2} ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code instead:

```
public int[] frequency(int[] tennumbers){
int[] frequency = new int[100];
for(int i=0; i< tennumbers.length ; i++){
frequency[tennumbers[i]]++;
}
return frequency;
}
```

That way you can know the frequency of, for example '60' by accessing the 60th index of your frequency array. like this:

```
int[] freq=frequency(tennumbers);
int sixtyFrequency=frequ[60];
```

Comment: direct addressing? What if some number in `tennumbers` is `>= 100`?

Comment: this is just an example of an approach, I thought it's still less complex than his original one